# Removing old Apple ID

Tags: iphone

When trying to update, or download apps from app store, my old Apple ID is being used. How do I remove it and use my new one?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What have you tried so far? Have you looked for relevant options in Settings app?

Comment: You can't just 'remove' an Apple ID, unless you want to re-purchase everything, including the iOS itself. Everything belongs to the ID, not the device or the human holding it.

Comment: Like this perhaps? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352540/asking-for-old-apple-id-when-trying-to-install-an-app?

Comment: you can change the primary email or phone number of your Apple ID. Add new email address and remove the older one! https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667#otheraddress

Comment: Or to remove it totally, You can go to appleid.apple.com and delete all the data associated if you want and sign into your iPhone's settings-> iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "change apple id appstore iphone" I stumbled into this page which shows how to do this on an iPhone.

[image: ss1]

Once you've signed out you can either sign in or create a new Apple ID.

> - Log in to another Apple account that already exists by entering the appropriate login details at that screen, OR
> - Create a new Apple ID by tapping on the “Create New Apple ID” button, which automatically logs in with the new Apple ID when
>     finished

#### References

- [How to Change the Apple ID on iPhone, iPad, & iPod Touch](http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/01/change-apple-id-ios/)